# How to delete a rows pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove a row in a `pandas` `df` plus the following `row`. For the `df` below I want to remove the `row` when the value in `Code` is equal to `X`. But I also want to remove the subsequent `row` as well.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Code' : ['A','A','B','C','X','A','B','A'],
    'Int' : [0,1,1,2,3,3,4,5],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

If I use this code it removes the desired `row`. But I can't use the same for value `A` as there are other rows that contain `A`, which are required.

```
df = df[df.Code != 'X']
```

So my intended output is:

```
  Code  Int
0    A    0
1    A    1
2    B    1
3    C    2
4    B    4
5    A    5
```

I need something like `df = df[df.Code != 'X'] +1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `shift`

```
df.loc[(df.Code!='X')&(df.Code.shift()!='X'),]
Out[99]: 
 Code  Int
0    A    0
1    A    1
2    B    1
3    C    2
6    B    4
7    A    5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the index of the element you want to delete, and then you can simply delete at that index twice:

```
>>> i = df[df.Code == 'X'].index
>>> df.drop(df.index[[i]], inplace=True)
>>> df.drop(df.index[[i]], inplace=True, errors='ignore')
>>> df
  Code  Int
0    A    0
1    A    1
2    B    1
3    C    2
6    B    4
7    A    5
```

Comment: this fails if the last row contains an 'X'